# Navbar items sitting on top of each other instead of next to

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Navbar items are sitting on top of each other when creating a `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` while they are meant to sit next to each other. I have followed the instructions on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) As far as I'm concerned my code is right.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>
            </div>



            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/homebrainbox/pen/aVwmoJ)

Comment: so you want the list to go under the title?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pasting your example into [bootply](https://www.bootply.com) seems to work fine.  I'd check that your script & stylesheet files are correctly included in your page.

--Edit--

I actually do see the issue after reducing the browser width match one of the smaller media queries (responsive mode).  The code you're using is working correctly, but is based on an incomplete example which wouldn't collapse down to the hamburger/triple-bar icon, as Bootstrap navbar's typically do.

You might be better served to review the code example from the Bootstrap website directly:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Comment: Thank you, you seem to be right about bootply, although I'm trying to run my code on Codepen: https://codepen.io/homebrainbox/pen/aVwmoJ

Comment: I see that you're missing the bootstrap js file from the settings panel, but it also appears to be fine here.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by 'appear to be fine here'? Where is 'here?' Also, the Bootstrap library has been added in the settings.

Comment: The menu items were all laid out correctly in a horizontal layout when I visited your codepen example.  If that is not the problem you're experiencing, you should edit your question to describe the problem in greater detail.

Comment: When I run the code, the items are not laid out horizontally, like in your case, but on top of each other. The question doesn't need rephrasing. Thanks for your help, it looks like the issue is not with the code itself them.

Comment: The code is right. It slipped my mind that the navbar, being responsive, rearranged the items due to the smaller screen.